# Should I use NoSQL for a project management app like Citrix Podio?

Tags: sql, database, nosql, podio

I'm thinking about developing an app similar to Podio, where you can create different "Apps" with personalized fields. I understand that this couldn't work on a SQL database because the fields (columns) would have to be pre-defined in the table, but I want those fields to be dynamic, for example having one app with 2 text fields and 3 number fields, and another app with a text field, a date field, and a number field... I've never worked with NoSQL before, that's why I'm asking.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

NoSQL is a great approach as the documents fields are not specified. You can insert whatever data schema you would like.

You can check https://www.mongodb.com/ and
https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/database for a cloud based database hosting.